# Are random variable $Y$ and $Z$ independent?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ has Uniform$(0,1)$ distribution. Let $0<a<b<1$ and define $Y=I_{(0,b)}(X)$ and $Z:=I_{(a,1)}(X)$ where $I_A$ denotes the indictor function.

Question: Are $Y$ and $Z$ independent? and what is $E[Y|Z]$?

My try: I calculate that the pdf of $Y$ and $Z$ are $f_Y(0)=1-b$, $f_Y(1)=b$, $f_Z(0)=a$, and $f_Z(1)=1-a$. Now I try to find out the joint distribution $f_{Y,Z}$ so that I can try to prove/disprove $f_{Y,Z}=f_Yf_Z$. But I got stuck on how to compute the joint distribution $f_{Y,Z}$...

Any help is really welcome!

update: I notice that by noting $P(\{Y=0,Z=0\})=P(\{b<x<1\}\cap \{0<x<a\})= P(\varnothing)=0\neq a(1-b)=P(Y=0)P(Z=0)$

So they are dependent. Am I correct?

I am still trying to compute $E[Y|Z]$...

Comment: Did you succeed to apply the law of total expectation to compute E(Y|Z)? Since you quickly accepted the answer that is making this suggestion, it would seem that you did--and I am curious to see the method and the result you got because I see no way to compute E(Y|Z) using the law of total expectation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Yes, I think your argument is fine (if the events you put there are consistent with your definition of $\operatorname I_{(a, b)}(X)$).
2. For $\operatorname E [Y \mid Z]$, it would be helpful to use the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).